# Is there an easy way to remove 'Style' attributes from all elements of a particular type in Xaml?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, expression-blend, styles

Okay,...I've recently inherited a downright shocking Silverlight 4 application and the Xaml is worse than you could possibly imagine.  I'm going through a clean up operation and I'm looking to save time if I can.

One of my problems is that I've got a bajillion `Button` controls; some have a `Style` set and some don't. I need a quick and easy way (if one exists) to remove all of the `Style` attributes from any `Button` (or whatever) that has one set. Is this possible?

I have access to VS2010, KaXaml, XamlPad and Blend 4.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about this question so in response to Robert Claypool's question,...No, not really.

What I actually did was remove all the styles and go through the big daunting errors list one by one.  I tried a little find and replace magic first but that failed miserably no matter how clever my Regex got.

No choice here but to just hand-ball it I'm afraid.